# .Net SOAP consumer application is caught by norton server antivirus

Tags: c#, antivirus

My windows forms application developed in .Net version 4.0 to consume a third party soap service is caught by norton sever antivirus as SONAR.MalTraffic!gen3. This application run round the clock to provide data to the third party service with desktop user privilege.
How to check what code leads to report the application as a malware?

Comment: I don't think that is how a virus scanner works. they don't decompile your code to see if it is a virus. It might be a resource file that you include that happens to have the same signature. Just exclude your exe for the Norton AV scan. Alternatively report a false positive to Norton so they can update their signature files.

Comment: No resource files added to the executable, creates an array of base64 converted image files instead for uploading to the third party service. Using maximum 3 mb for the whole files. Could not exclude the folder since the antivirus manged by their server team.

Comment: re arrange some classes / strings, re-compile and hope for the best (or install Norton AV server yourself and scan). or maybe sign your exe and dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool  but I'm not sure if an AV product takes a signed exe/dll into account as safe.